# Pass parameters to function

Tags: php, laravel, routes

Is there a way to pass parameters to function from route without wildcard.
For example to access query string data we need to add wildcard to route

```
Route::post('reg/{param}','controller@func');
```

But I don't wanna use wildcard or query string. I want to pass data to function as a parameter

Comment: Use a POST route

Comment: That was a typo btw its post,as i have clearly mentioned I don't want to use wildcard  to access data from a function i want to pass data as a parameter to a function from route

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly: in your controller all you have to do is write your `func` method as follows:

```
public function func($param) {}
```

Laravel will automatically put whatever is in `{param}` to `$param`. So if you POSTed to your server `http://server/reg/foo`, then `$param` would get the value "foo". It is not in the ordering of the variable but the name of the variable. So if you named your variable `{fooX}` it would be passed to a controller method named `$fooX`.

You can put more than one variable like so:

```
Route::post('reg/{paramX}/{paramY}','controller@func');
```

and define your method as

```
public function func($paramX, $paramY) {}
```

Comment: As i have clearly mentioned i dont wanna use wildcard technique.

Comment: I didn't know you called them wildcards. The manual calls them route parameters https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#route-parameters . In that case your only option will be to put your inputs in the request body -- in x-www-form-urlencoded format or json format. Then get the passed value from the `Request` parameter

Answer (score 0):

No, that is how the Laravel router works. But you still can access them from the request. Just like you may have done in the "old days", from the global variable `$_GET` or `$_POST`.

Just define your route without wildcards, like this:

```
Route::post('reg','controller@func');
```

And inside the function use `$request->query('param_name');`